# Send python/graypy messages directly to Elasticsearch with GELF input?

Tags: python, logging, elasticsearch

I can send GELF messages from Python logging using [graypy](https://github.com/severb/graypy). I can receive messages in Elasticsearch using the [GELF input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-gelf.html). But graypy sends over UPD and Elasticsearch receives over TCP. How does one send logging messages directly from Python to Elasticsearch?